# AngularJS - showing an item only if none of the booleans in a collection are true

Tags: angularjs

I would like to show the button in the code only if none of the aspects in $scope.aspects are true.

```
<aspect-form ng-repeat="aspect in aspects | filter:{active: true}">
</aspect-form>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Save</a>
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without binding to a function on the scope like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
  ng-if="(aspects | filter:{active: true}).length === 0">Save</a>
```

Comment: nice and nifty! I guess this is the most minimal solution, but perhaps not the most readable one.

Comment: I don't know that I totally agree that it's less readable, given that you have to go to the controller to see the internals of the function. But that's a matter of style/preference. But there is a practical distinction to be made here... binding to a function is going to cause the code inside the function to be repeatedly evaluated in the application loop, whereas I *think* there will be better optimization for change tracking if you bind to specific members that can be evaluated on the scope.

Comment: I'll just go ahead and be self-promoting and remind you to mark it as accepted if you think it's the best answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In situations like these I like to use the array.every() and array.some() functions:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" ng-if="allAspectsFalse()">Save</a>

$scope.allAspectsFalse = function() {
  return $scope.aspects.every(function(aspect) {
    return !aspect.active;
  });
}
```

Comment: Not supported in IE8?

Comment: If you're still on IE8 that's the least of your worries :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if` in the `a` element, and give it a function that evaluates to true only when all of the aspects in `$scope.aspects` are false.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-if="allAspectsAreFalse()">Save</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found a solution. Mine is using ng-show instead but is practically the same. I will show the whole solution.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" ng-show="someAspectShowing()">Save</a>
```

and in the controller I have defined the function:

```
$scope.someAspectShowing = function() {
  for(index=0; index < $scope.aspects.length; ++index) {
    if($scope.aspects[index].active === true) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
  };
```

Comment: Cool. Just keep in mind that `ng-if` removes the element from the DOM tree entirely. `ng-show`/`ng-hide` show/hide the element through CSS with `display: none;`.